# django import export not import excel file with foreignkey msssql

Tags: python, django

i have a resource.py

```
class bankid_resource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
    model = bankID
```

and have model.py

```
class bankID(models.Model):
bankIdN = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
userID = models.ForeignKey('UserDetails', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
CardN = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

and in my view.py  iwant to import excel file with this function

```
def import_bankid_list(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    bankids = bankid_resource()
    dataset = Dataset()
    new_bankids = request.FILES['myFile']
    data_import = dataset.load(new_bankids.read())
    result = bankids.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)
    if not result.has_errors():
        bankids.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
        return redirect('import_bankid_list')
    else:
        return redirect('')

return render(request, 'personel/import.html')
```

but data not import because have a ForeignKey in exported csv file.
my database is mssql.
i need help to solve the problem
any file without ForeignKey  will import corecctly.